# Displaying images in a specific frame in Python using TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display images in my game, which in time will correspond to rooms.

I have three main frames and I want to display images in the one called 'frame 3', but I am not unable to get the picture itself to display!
I made a method called RoomImages which is supposed to handle the roomImages. I have called this method in my constructormethod for the whole App class.
It displays no error messages and therefore I am unsure where the missing logic is.

I have attached a picture of what the output shows:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W9hh.png)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from Game import Game
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class App():

    # Creates a Frame for the application
    # and populates the GUI ...
    def __init__(self, root):
        #super().__init__(master=win)
        self.game = Game()

    #A menubar with the options Quit' which destroys the window
    #  and 'about' which displays a message box with the info from the method showAbout
        menubar = tk.Menu()
        menubar.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.destroy)
        menubar.add_command(label="About", command=self.showAbout)
        root.config(menu=menubar)



        # Create two frames owned by the window root
        # In order to use multiple layout managers, the frames
        # cannot share a parent frame. Here both frames are owned
        # by a top level instance root.
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=250, bg='WHITE', borderwidth=2)
        self.frame1.pack_propagate(0)   # Prevents resizing
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=150, bg='LIGHT GREY', borderwidth=2, padx=175)
        self.frame2.grid_propagate(0)   # Prevents resizing
        self.frame3 = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=250, bg='LIGHT BLUE', borderwidth=2, padx=275)
        self.frame3.grid_propagate(0)  # Prevents resizing
        # This packs both frames into the root window ...
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.frame3.pack()

        #image canvas for frame3 to display the current room
        self.canvas_for_image = tk.Canvas(self.frame3, bg='LIGHT GREY', height=250, width=600, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_for_image.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=0, pady=0)
        #self.canvas_for_image.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)


        self.frame3.columnconfigure(0, pad=5)
        self.frame3.columnconfigure(1, pad=5)
        self.frame3.rowconfigure(0, pad=5)
        self.frame3.rowconfigure(1, pad=5)

        #make a gridstructure for frame2 to be able to precisely place my buttons.
        self.frame2.columnconfigure(0, pad=5)
        self.frame2.columnconfigure(1, pad=5)
        self.frame2.columnconfigure(2, pad=5)
        self.frame2.columnconfigure(3, pad=5)
        self.frame2.columnconfigure(4, pad=5)
        self.frame2.columnconfigure(5, pad=5)
        self.frame2.rowconfigure(0, pad=5)
        self.frame2.rowconfigure(1, pad=5)
        self.frame2.rowconfigure(2, pad=5)
        self.frame2.rowconfigure(3, pad=5)

        # Now add some useful widgets ...
        self.textArea1 = tk.Label(self.frame1, text='')
        self.textArea1.pack()
        self.cmdArea = tk.Entry(self.frame2, text='')
        self.cmdArea.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self.buildGUI()

        self.roomImages()

    def showAbout(self):
        """uses the messagebox import to display info about the game"""
        messagebox.showinfo("About", "A classic whodunnit where you have to find out who the murder is!")


    def buildGUI(self):
        self.doCmd = tk.Button(self.frame2, text='Run command',
                               fg='black', bg='blue',
                               command=self.doCommand)
        self.doCmd.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.goDown = tk.Button(self.frame2, text='Down',
                               fg='black', bg='red',
                               command=self.processDownCommand)
        self.goDown.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.goUp = tk.Button(self.frame2, text='Up',
                                fg='black', bg='red',
                                command=self.processUpCommand)
        self.goUp.grid(row =0, column=1)

        self.goLeft = tk.Button(self.frame2, text='Left',
                                fg='black', bg='red',
                                command=self.processLeftCommand)
        self.goLeft.grid(row=1,column = 0)

        self.goRight = tk.Button(self.frame2, text='Right',
                                fg='black', bg='red',
                                command=self.processRightCommand)
        self.goRight.grid(row=1, column =2)


        self.help = tk.Button(self.frame2, text='Help',
                              fg='black', bg='green',
                              command=self.processHelpCommand)
        self.help.grid(row=1, column=4)

        self.textArea1.configure(text=self.game.printWelcome())


    


    def roomImages(self):
        self.imageDict = {'apple': 'apple.png', 'banana': 'banana.png', 'bar': 'bar.png', 'cherries': 'cherries.png',
                          'grapes': 'grapes.png', 'lemon': 'lemon.png', 'melon': 'melon.png', 'orange': 'orange.png'}
        self.apple = 'apple'
        self.apple = f'images/{self.imageDict[self.apple]}'
        #adding images
        self.r1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.apple))
        self.r1Label = tk.Label(self.frame3, image=self.r1)


      


    def main():
        win = tk.Tk()                           # Create a window
        win.title("Adventure World with GUI")   # Set window title
        win.geometry("700x400")                 # Set window size
        win.resizable(False, False)             # Both x and y dimensions ...
    
    
    
        # Create the GUI as a Frame
        # and attach it to the window ...
        myApp = App(win)
    
        # Call the GUI mainloop ...
        win.mainloop()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to call pack or grid on the `r1Label`. Also only use one geometry manager, not both pack and grid.

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a fair amount of code that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem.